# problems with binding <%# in Custom Control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

so I've finally started building custom controls instead of using functions which return chunks of HTML ;) But I'm running into a problem. I want to pass parameters to the control, say, "X":

```
<some:MessageControl runat="server" X=<%# "asd" %> />
```

My code behind looks like this:

```
public partial class MessageControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    String x = "";
    public String X 
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value;}
    }    
}
```

When I output the value of `x` in the control,

```
x: <%= X %>
```

it is empty.
If I pass on "asd" directly as in

```
 <some:MessageControl runat="server" X="asd" />
```

X gets the correct value.

What's happening here? How can I get this to work? Any suggestions are appreciated,
Nicolas

**Edit: Some more context.** Basically I want to be able to insert the control on a number of pages without settings its properties in the code behind, but still be able to set its visibility by calling a (varying) method from the containing page.

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" Src="MyPage.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyPage" %>
<%@ Register Src="MessageControl.ascx" TagName="MessageControl" TagPrefix="some" %>
<html>
  <body>
    <some:MessageControl runat="server" Visible=<%# SomeBoolMethodFromContaining Page%> />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For <%= SomeMethods or Property %> expression you need to call DataBind() method in parent page or control that contains this expression on OnPageLoad event or another.

For example here code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataBind();
}

protected string Hello
{
   get { return "hello";}
}
```

Here html part of the page:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Id="Literal1" Text="<%= Hello  %>"/>
```

For Visible property use code above and <%# Method or Property%> expression. For text use <%= %> expression. It renders output as a plain text.

Hope it will help you with your question.

Best regards, Dima.

Comment: that's it! Seems very logical now that I know it ;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
X='<%# "asd" %>'
```

Note the single quotes.

Comment: give some context into how you're using the control. Binding may syntax like that may not be applicable. <%= may work.

Comment: thanks for your efforts; please check my update, hope this makes things a bit clearer! <%= doesn't work, btw

Comment: You could always give your control an Id and set its properties in the code behind.

Comment: Yea but passing on dynamic parameters from the .aspx page seems like a useful thing to be able to do...

Comment: you could be dealing with page lifecycle issues. Just give it a try.